# How to call a returned value to java function here

Tags: java, function, return

This is the code I have written to check for armstrong nos, but am unable to access the value returned in the check() function.

Error  : Cannot find Symbol - variable sum

How am I to fix this..

Also tell if this is the way I should use the main method to access execute the program and jump from one function to another or is there another method which will be better.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class Arm_check
    {
        int n=0;
        public void main()
        {
            getnum();
        }

        void getnum()
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a No.");
            Scanner Prakhar=new Scanner(System.in);
            n=Prakhar.nextInt();
            check();
            int ori=n;
        }

        int check()
        {
            int digits=(int)Math.floor(Math.log10(n)+1);
            System.out.println("No of Digits :"+digits);
            int a[]=new int[digits];
            int sum=0;
            for(int i=0;i<digits;i++)
            {
                a[i]=n%10;
                n=n/10;
            }
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
                sum=(int)Math.pow(a[i],3)+sum;
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
            return sum;
            dispsum();
        }

        void dispsum()
        {
            int z=check(sum);

            if(z==ori)
            {
                System.out.println("No. is Armstrong");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("No. is not Armstrong");
        }
    }
```

Thanks..

Comment: You defined `sum` inside of `check()` but you are trying to use it inside of `dispsum()`. Also, check doesn't take any parameters so you don't say `check(sum)`, it's just `check()`.

Comment: And you're trying to pass the unknown "sum" into check(), which takes no argument. And sum is trying to call dispsum after it returns, and dispsum is trying to call sum...

Comment: I just want to know how to use the sum variable in dispsum function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ...

        System.out.println(sum);
        dispsum(sum);
        return sum;
    }

    void dispsum(int z)
    {
        if(z==ori)
    ...
```

Comment: Given that you check-marked it, I presume it is now working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually "return" a value from the 'check' function.  Try something like...

```
int thissum = check ();
```

Then you can pass 'thissum' to other functions.